# Problem editing .fla files

Tags: flash

How to edit the .fla file code and save it in the .swf format?

I downloaded the trial version of adobe flash.

I am able to see the output frame but not source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Movie Explorer" ("Windows" menu) will let you see scripts that are in the .fla file, and you can edit them in the "Actions" window. But in most cases, there is little or no code in the .fla file, instead code is in accompanying .as files.

Comment: thanks a lot! I can see a lot of code when I clicked the "Actions" in the menu

Answer (score 1):

You need [Adobe Flash](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash/) to open .fla files.

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>F9</kbd> in Adobe Flash CS5.5.